# how do i intergrate and initialize filesystem of laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, filesystems, laravel-5

i followed this steps https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem

> composer update "graham-campbell/flysystem": "~1.0" DONE
>
> php artisan vendor:publish DONE

i have this code

```
public function store()
    {
      $file = Request::file('images');
      $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,                     File::get($file));
      $entry = new Fileentry();
      $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
      $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $entry->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
   }
```

my form

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<h1>Create New Timelinemeta</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('timelinemeta/store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Images</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

having an error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Storage' not found
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to import `Storage` class because it's a facade.

Add:

```
use Storage;
```

at top of your controller.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Storage;

class YourController {
   ...
}
```

Comment: `use Storage;`
`use File;`
`use Fileentry;`
Error: Class 'Fileentry' not found

Comment: @MarlonBuendia So the error is now different so problem with `Storage` was solved. I don't know what is `Fileentry` here - is it your custom class or if it's comming from some package.

Answer (score 3):

you can also do :

```
$disk = \Storage::disk('s3');
```

Means you must prepend \ before the storage